# How do I open up a new window in Visual Studio code based on a previous commit hash?

Tags: git

Let's say at a previous commit some feature was working and I altered the code related to that feature after the commit. I want to compare the code from the working commit with the current code. What is the best way to do this?
`
I can run `git checkout commithash` but it means I have to switch back and forth between the current branch and old commit.

###### Update

It turns out there is a git command designed for this exact use case:

1. Get the  of the working code.
2. Checkout the branch where your bug is.
3. Run `git diff <commit-hash>`

If it's hard to pinpoint the code differences due e.g. the volume of code, try running `git diff <commit-hash> -- file-path`. This will show the differences in a VIM editor.

If the Vim editor isn't helping try:

1. `git checkout <commit-hash>`
2. Copy the file
3. `git checkout og_branch`
4. Create a new file e.g. settings_old.py and paste the old working code in it.
5. Open up each file side by side to compare.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? Otherwise you could just close and delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not work like that.

You can either use VS Code external Plugins (such as **GitLens**), or use git tooling (**gitk** for example) to inspect old changes.

`gitk <COMMIT-HASH>`

I would go with the first option and install **GitLens** - it's a great plugin that allows you to do exactly what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'm checking them out now!

I do seem to be able to checkout a commit hash e.g. git checkout <commit-hash>  in VSC. Are you saying that it shouldn't be used like that?

Comment: you can, but doing `git checkout hash` will **change** the current folder state, it wont give you access to both current state and the hash's state. so without external tools/plugins, its not a straight forward task

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a lot of files or even directories with an external tool, another solution is to use `git worktree` feature.

You could checkout code at a given commit inside another 'wortree' directory with the command:

```
git worktree add --detach <path-to-new-folder-outside-current-repo> <commit-hash>
```

Then you have your current branch and the checked out commit folders side by side and you could open 2 instances of Vscode or use an external tool able to compare directories.

See git worktree doc for more details: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree